# Is this achievable on wordpress?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

Trying to make a site similar to this theme https://www.beefitswhatsfordinner.com/, is this achievable on WordPress?

I am trying to avoid code as I will be using plugins but below is what I have currently tried.

The platform is wordpress, page builder is elementor, this HTML snippet is inside the HTML tag of an elementor block

```
<sectiona>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>
            Button 1
        </a>
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/1.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
            Button 2
        </a>
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/2.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
            Button 3
        </a>
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/3.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
            Button 4
        </a>
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/4.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
            Button 5
        </a>
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/5.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
            Button 6
        </a>
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/6.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<style>
 sectiona{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 }

ul{
width: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 2px;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 2px;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 2px;
text-align: center;

 }

 ul li
 {
 list-style: none;
  } 

 ul li a
 {
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 24px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.5s
  }

 ul li a:hover
 {
 background: #ff0;
 color: #000;
  }

 sectiona img
 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -2;
transition: 1s;
opacity: 0;
 }

ul li a:hover + img
{
opacity: 1;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, ulvayaam. We answer mostly direct questions here about code. You need to show us that you've tried before and we can help you from there.

Comment: alright i have already tried to replicate it in wordpress using elementor with html tag

Comment: @KGreene please see now, I edited the post with code

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is just a CMS.

So you could build any site with it the hardest part here is the frontend.

you can expand posttypes and add posttypes, add categories to achieve more complex structures of content.

Comment: Yeah i know, but is there a way to replicate the homepage of the site, or a similar theme,